Show that $|f(x)| \leq \frac{|x^2|}{2}$ if $||f'(x)||\leq |x|$
Let $U \subset R^n$ be an open and convex set, with $0 \in U$. Let $f:U\rightarrow R^m$ be a $C^1$ function such that $f(0)=0$. Suppose $||f'(x)||\leq |x|$ for every $x \in U$. Show that $|f(x)| \leq \frac{|x^2|}{2}$
My attempt: I can solve this if m=1
Let $\gamma(t)=tx, t \in [0,1]$ be the line connecting $0$ to $x$. We have $\gamma \subset U$ since $U$ is convex. Then, since $f$ is $C^1$, we have:
$f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^1<f'(tx),x>dt$, then, by Cauchy-Schwartz and hypothesis:
$|f(x)|\leq |x|^2\int_0^1tdt=\frac{|x|^2}{2}$
I also tried to use the mean value inequality for vector fields, which states:
$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq||f'(\epsilon)||\;|x-y|$, where $||\;||$ is a matrix norm and $\epsilon=\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y, \lambda \in [0,1]$
But using that, we miss the factor $\frac{1}{2}$.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Your first proof works verbatim even when the domain and target of $f$ are Banach spaces. Maybe you’re only familiar with the FTC when the target space is $\Bbb{R}$, but it holds more generally as well. You also don’t need Cauchy-Schwarz (i.e a Hilbert space structure), because you can just use the definition of the operator norm in order to bound $| Df_{tx}(x)|$.

@peek-a-boo I don't know much about the bound for the operator norm, can you point me somewhere I can read about it?

Just google the operator norm; it’s a very simple concept. But for treatments of differential calculus in Banach spaces, look at Loomis and Sternberg chapter 3, Henri Cartan’s Differential Calculus, or Dieudonne’s Vol I.

@peek-a-boo in a general Banach space $X$, you also need the inequality $|\int_0^1 g(t)dt |\leq \int_0^1|g(t)|dt$, which is not completely trivial -- you can prove it along the same lines as the proof I give below for the OP's inequality, or by using Hahn-Banach to show that $|\int_0^1 g(t)dt| = \lambda(\int_{0}^{1} g(t)dt)$ for some $\lambda \in X'$ of norm $1$, and then noting that $\lambda(\int_0^1g(t)dt) = \int_0^1\lambda(g(t))dt$ so that you can apply the $1$-d inequality.

@krm2233 reducing to 1D via Hahn-Banach is one method, but for Riemann-integrable maps, this is pretty simple: it is obvious by the triangle inequality when $g$ is a step function (linear combinations of indicators of intervals), and by taking a suitable limit, you get it for all Riemann-integrable maps (in fact this proof works verbatim by replacing step functions by simple functions (linear combination of indicators of measurable sets)). But fair enough, I did treat this inequality as trivial when I wrote my comment, even though it’s not the most obvious.

@peek-a-boo: Sorry, I didn't mean to suggest it was particularly hard to prove! The triangle inequality for integrals feels to me to be of a very similar nature (and difficulty in terms of proof) to the one the OP asks about, and hence wanted to make its use explicit  (and I guess also to say that, while not a triviality, it is not hard to prove).

Let $g(x)= \langle f(x), u \rangle$ whre $u$ is a fixed unit vector. Then $g$ satisfies the same hypothesis as  $f$ and it is real valued. So $|g(x)|\leq \frac {|x|^{2}}2$. Taking sup over all unit vectors $u$ we get $|f(x)|\leq \frac {|x|^{2}}2$.

Can I just choose $u=\frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}$ on the last part?

Yes, that is correct.

Note that $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^1 f'((1-t)0+tx)x dt$. Using the inequality, we have $|f(x)| \le \int_0^1 t \|x\|^2 ft = {1 \over 2} \|x\|^2$.

You can also prove this using a strategy that also proves the mean value inequality:
The result is trivial for $x=0$ so suppose that $x \in U\backslash \{0\}$ and let $g(t)=f(t.x)/\|x\|^2$, so that $g'(t) = \|x\|^{-2}f'(tx)(x)$, and we must show that $g(1)\leq 1/2$. By assumption
$$
\|g'(t)\|\leq \|x\|^{-2}\|f'(tx)\|.\|x\| = \|x\|^{-1}\|f'(tx)\|\leq |t|.
$$
Now, for any $\epsilon\geq 0$ let
$$
S_{\epsilon}:= \left\{t \in [0,1]:  |g(t)|\leq \frac{1}{2}t^2+\epsilon \right\}
$$
Since $g$ is continuous $0 \in S_{\epsilon} \subseteq [0,1]$ is a closed non-empty subset of $[0,1]$ and hence $b=b_\epsilon= \sup(S_\epsilon) \in S_{\epsilon}$. Now if $b_\epsilon=1$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $\|g(1)\|\leq 1/2+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and so $\|g(1)\|\leq 1/2$ or $f(x)\leq \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2$ as required. Thus we are reduced to checking the following:
Claim: For all $\epsilon>0$ we have $b_\epsilon=1$.
Let $b=b_{\epsilon}$ and suppose that $b<1$. Since $g$ is differentiable at $b$ we have
$$
g(b+h)=g(b)+h.g'(b) + |h|\eta(h),
$$
where $\eta(h)\to 0 = \eta(0)$ as $h \to 0$. Thus
$$
\|g(b+h)-g(b)\| \leq \||h|(|b| + |\eta(h)|)
$$
and since $\eta(h)\to 0$ as $h \to 0$, there is an $r>0$ such that for all $h \in (-r,r)$ we have $\|\eta(h)\| < (1-b)$ so that for $h \in (-r,r)$ we have $\|g(b+h)-g(b)\|< |h|$. Since $b \in S_{\epsilon}$, we have, for $h \in (0,r)$,
$$
\|g(b+h)\|\leq \|g(b)\|+ \|g(b+h)-g(b)\| \leq \frac{1}{2}b^2 +\epsilon + b.h < \frac{1}{2}(b+h)^2 +\epsilon
$$
But then clearly $[b,b+r)\subseteq S_{\epsilon}$, contradicting the hypothesis that $b=b_{\epsilon} = \sup(S_\epsilon)$. Thus we must have $b_{\epsilon} =1$ for all $\epsilon>0$ as claimed.
